# How can I add cls file to my TexShop?

Tags: mactex, texshop

now I have a question about the MacTex, I have a cls file, and according to other post, I have put it in the path ~/Library/texmf/tex/latax and sudo texhash it, but when I try to use \documentclass of my cls in texshop, and compile, it will report error like the cls is not found, anyone has any ideas of it? Thank you very much!

Comment: Except for the fact that the last directory should better be named `latex` (;-) , that should be fine (you don’t even need to run `mktexlsr`).  What’s the *exact* error message that you get?

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti I got ! Latex Error : File 'liuthesis.cls' not found.(liuthesis.cls is the one I put in the .../latex path)

Comment: @Tiuri Haha no, I mean I misspell here, I do create .../latex

Comment: If you open a Terminal window and type `kpsewhich liuthesis.cls` what do you get?

Comment: @AlanMunn I do like the post that you mention, and I put cls file in /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/local and texhash, it seems wroking now! Thank you so much!

Comment: But that's *not* what you should have done (although it does work that way too.)  It's much simpler to put things in your `~/Library/texmf` folder.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti Thank you so much, I follow the post Alan mention, now it seems working!

Comment: @AlanMunn OK, I try this, if I put the cls into /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/local and kpsewhich liuthesis.cls, it will show the exact directory, but if I put it into the ~/Library/texmf, it will show nothing

Comment: @sunboy612: It looks like you are the only user of your computer, aren’t you?  (Or, at least, you have system administration priviledges…)

Comment: That's very odd. Are you sure you have installed MacTeX and not a version via MacPorts or brew?  What does `kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFHOME` return?

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti Yes, I am the only user!

Comment: @AlanMunn I downloaded and installed MacTex from their official website, and I run kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFHOME, it will show /Users/bo/Library/texmf (Sorry first time to use Latex)

Comment: That's the correct path. So the fact that `kpsewhich` doesn't find `liuthesis.cls` when it's in `~/Library/texmf/tex/latex` is really surprising.

Comment: @sunboy612:  In that case, I’d say that placing your personal files inside `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/local` is even batter than placing them in your personal texmf tree, since they will be available to other users as well (should you ever have a guest!).  Yet the fact that they are not found when you put them inside `~/Library/texmf/tex/latex/` remains mysterious.

Comment: @AlanMunn I think I found the reason, because I just open Finder, and it shows the Macintosh HD, and I open it has a folder called Library, I think I create the /texmf here. Right now I go to the directory ~/Library and create again, and it's working! But thank you very much!

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti I think I found the reason, because I just open Finder, and it shows the Macintosh HD, and I open it has a folder called Library, I think I create the /texmf here. Right now I go to the directory ~/Library and create again, and it's working! But thank you very much!

Comment: That makes sense. Yes, it's   `~/Library` not `/Library` that should contain the local files.